# How to add images one by one into tableviewcell by clicking addImage button in swift4

Tags: swift4

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{


        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var addImage: UIImage!

        let animalNames = ["lion","monky","tiger"]
        let animalImages = [UIImage(named: "lion"), UIImage(named: "monky"), UIImage(named: "tiger")]




        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return animalImages.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell",for:indexPath) as! ImageWithTableViewCell
            cell.image1.image=self.animalImages[indexPath .row]
            cell.label1.text=self.animalNames[indexPath .row]
            return cell
        }

       @IBAction func addingImages(_ sender: UIButton) {

            //what code I have to write here
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want array to mutable declare it as `var` instead of let. and Create 1 var `numberOfRecordtoShow`

```
var animalNames = ["lion","monky","tiger"]
var animalImages = [UIImage(named: "lion"), UIImage(named: "monky"), UIImage(named: "tiger")]
var numberOfRecordtoShow = 1
```

Increate `numberOfRecordtoShow` by 1 till array count.

```
@IBAction func addingImages(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if numberOfRecordtoShow > animalNames.count{
      return
   }

   numberOfRecordtoShow = numberOfRecordtoShow + 1
   //reload table now
   tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return numberOfRecordtoShow

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much bro but I want to display images one by one when I click addImage button. by writing above code I got three images at a time this I don't want .  I want  chance to add images .

Comment: please help me as much as possible